# How to refresh UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I get one problem is that,

This's `showads` function.

```
[self.mMainView addSubview:adViewController.view];
//...(my function to display ads)
```

This's `hideads` function.

```
 //...(my function to hide ads)
 [[AdViewController sharedAdViewController].view removeFromSuperview];
 [self.mMainView setNeedsDisplay];
```

---

The `mMainView` is a `UIView`.
The `AdViewController` is a `UIViewController`.

The problems is that after calling `showads` fucntion, the my ads display on `mMainView`. But after calling `hideads` function, the my ads don't disappear, it still appear on `mMainView`.

Note: After calling `hideads` and make an interrupt then resume the app, the my ads will disappear.

So, i want to remove it, could you please explain a bit in more detail and show me how to fix it if you can pls ?

Comment: Are you sure that view: adViewController.view is exactly the same as that one: [AdViewController sharedAdViewController].view ?

Comment: yes. because adViewController = [AdViewController sharedAdViewController];

Comment: Can you show your singleton code, how do you create that view?

Comment: This's showads function
if(adViewController == nil)
    {
        adViewController = [AdViewController sharedAdViewController];
    }
    [self.mMainView addSubview:adViewController.view];
    [self.mMainView sendSubviewToBack: [AdViewController sharedAdViewController].view];

Comment: [adViewController showBanner]

Comment: can you double check that the view is exactly the same? try this UIView *adView = [AdViewController sharedAdViewController].view; check the address in debug and see if its exactly the same when you add the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call `setNeedsDisplay` when removing or adding subviews. The fact that it updates after an interrupt makes me suspect that you're not calling `[[AdViewController sharedAdViewController].view removeFromSuperview];` on the *main* thread. What is the context of that code?

If it's not on the main thread, you can schedule on it:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [[AdViewController sharedAdViewController].view removeFromSuperview];
});
```